# LFTP script file arguments

Tags: arguments, lftp

I've got an issue while using LFTP with some script files.

```
lftp -f download.lftp
```

the script looks something like that for now:

```
open -u someurl
mirror -i "somefile*.zip" --only-missing
...
```

somehow the mirror -i argument must be set to some value, provided by the calling script.

Is there a way to pass some argument(s) to LFTP scripts?

thanks in advance for your help!